# JSON from REST service returning under wrong name

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, netbeans, typescript

I am currently building an angularJS/typescript web app with a Netbeans RESTful backend. I have my typescript interface set up for a vendor as follows:

```
interface Vendor {
    vendorno: number,
    name: string,
    address1: string,
    city: string,
    province: string,
    postalcode: string,
    phone: string,
    vendortype: string,
    email: string;
}
```

When I call my rest service to pull back all of the vendors from my JavaDB it is pulling back JSON named under a completely different scheme than my interface, and in order to get my angular directives to work, I have to reference the naming scheme of this JSON instead and it causing things to break:

```
[{"vendorAddress":"543 Sycamore Ave","vendorCity":"Toronto","vendorEmail":"bb@depot.ca","vendorName":"Big Bills Depot","vendorNo":1,"vendorPhone":"(999) 555-5555","vendorPostalcode":"N1P1N5","vendorProvince":"ON","vendorType":"Trusted"},
{"vendorAddress":"628 Richmond Street","vendorCity":"London","vendorEmail":"abc@supply.ca","vendorName":"ABC Supply Co.","vendorNo":2,"vendorPhone":"(519) 123-4567","vendorPostalcode":"N6C1L7","vendorProvince":"ON","vendorType":"Trusted"},
{"vendorAddress":"123 Main Boulevard","vendorCity":"Burlington","vendorEmail":"gs@shack.net","vendorName":"Gadget Shack","vendorNo":3,"vendorPhone":"(613) 444-3423","vendorPostalcode":"N3X5S2","vendorProvince":"ON","vendorType":"Unknown"}]
```

In order to display this vendor data in a table on my partial I would have to use the following angular bindings:

```
<div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 text-left">{{vend.vendorNo}}</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">{{vend.vendorName}}</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 text-center">{{vend.vendorCity}}</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 text-center">{{vend.vendorType}}</div>
```

Is there any reason for either angularJS or my Java REST service to be auto renaming my returned JSON to have these property names?

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place. If that's what you receive that is what server is sending ... unless you happen to be using any `$httpInterceptors` that are looping through the data and changing it, but that is highly unlikely and would be written into your angular app.

Comment: Are you using an ORM tool in the back-end?  You probably have an ORM layer that *maps* your database fields (such as `vendorCity`) into object field names (`city`).  However, that REST service seems to be driven directly from the backend database with the raw table column names.  This happens a *lot* in large projects where the backend, middle tier and client-side are developed by different teams.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any reason for either angularJS or my Java REST service to be auto renaming my returned JSON to have these property names

It isn't angular. Its probably the Java REST service.

One option is to update the interface to match what the server returns :

```
interface Vendor {
    vendorNo: number;
    vendorName: string;
    // so on ...
}
```